MimeKit's MimeParser Counts Some MBOX Emails Multiple Times and Splits Messages
I'm using MimeKit's MimeParser in C# to count the number of emails in an MBOX file. While the parser works well for most emails, I've encountered issues where certain emails are counted multiple times or split into two or three parts. Additionally, some emails trigger a "Failed to parse message headers" error, although the primary concern is the inaccurate counting and message splitting.
Here's the relevant portion of my code:
private void ContinueAfterError(Stream stream, MimeParser parser)
{
    long newPosition = parser.Position + 1024; 
    if (newPosition < stream.Length)
    {
        stream.Position = newPosition;
        parser.SetStream(stream, MimeFormat.Mbox);
    }
    else
    {
        Log("Reached end of stream or unable to skip ahead safely.");
    }
}

try
{
    int count = 0;

    if (!File.Exists(LoadFile))
    {
        Log($"File not found: {LoadFile}");
        MessageBox.Show($"The file '{LoadFile}' does not exist.", "File Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(LoadFile))
    {
        var parserOptions = new ParserOptions(); 
        var mboxParser = new MimeParser(parserOptions, fileStream, MimeFormat.Mbox);

        while (!mboxParser.IsEndOfStream)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = mboxParser.ParseMessage();
                if (message != null)
                {
                    count++;
                    Log($"Email {count}: Subject - {message.Subject}");
                    Log($"MBOX marker at message {count}: {mboxParser.MboxMarker}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception parseEx)
            {
                Log($"Failed to parse message: {parseEx.Message}");
                Log($"Error occurred near MBOX marker: {mboxParser.MboxMarker}");
                ContinueAfterError(fileStream, mboxParser);
            }
        }
    }

    _totalCount = count;
    UpdateLabelCount(count);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred while reading the file: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

I'm sharing a sample email from the problematic MBOX file below, which seems to cause the parser to count it as two messages:
From 
Delivered-To: abc@example.com
Received: by 2002:a2e:1bd3:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id c80csp351385ljf;
        Wed, 9 Oct 2019 07:00:43 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqzGFhG+0u+6BJKXJVb49sKOjUprwGeFbUyVp3dXD6GbcfqukQGoLrnrXr0RTURojG/tBf1h
X-Received: by 2002:a37:a24f:: with SMTP id l76mr3741010qke.429.1570629643364;
        Wed, 09 Oct 2019 07:00:43 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1570629643; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=qh4jM9/hpqPRFOOsAWV4Ms/ilSJlaXKfvHFfUtfaz4bacJjlFWra7dTYLKgFnzD/N3
         SdDWyia+6n/BYOxbKLo5EZR3lMIT6sucBAvifuVUHGBC5ZH1m+MCd8NKWpvcU6QYPaWN
         adZHnKJMbK0N6yLi4T7Hrg0wo94cV7j3nlDvUCNG8NXd7MghCifUs6Xw3jo89nokFDEB
         nKaBlQ2fP31Tyb9pn8ayCLso+ECdJeAR9Gi3H+W0N0BwKZlD9RVMpGJz+WHnCJt/kN93
         HuGG1SvKu4wKqNiGhSDaDZp5jnyJ/wMTvEo8tFDCty8VVqyIi92tABqMj2FCSKHPNOD2
         k6JA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=message-id:date:list-unsubscribe:subject:to:from:mime-version
         :dkim-signature;
        bh=6vK4ZIaKRuoctW8ihKzJLIIibzyHSKArzwsvWrMr93o=;
        b=WLugBo2BnUzkfrhD8cnZMdXHNGOdGYbEtVBIba7txBR9nOOWNtl+uGAszso2wt6HWg
         OT8xsXP3v4wCZOulgkNd/NbBKnA0+jPxLr4imF7t6UOYnN/wIkbqfEISdq1DAN7KD0i5
         1KVP+PUSMM12ve+ArUmu04EmaPCOpUPkUw8xQV2+TqLezDFxHV/GbCdJgv3nBAkWdcMI
         AhwoikGDCCB/ysbBRC5fE4XRNHBIJwBQBHHhUEglQd+m8g4TBhGHtFeTL5N2S/CghY5H
         ytI/KB9v2ia352XTHvBTKXGdxRDydKPwjaI+SF3eZH+Kg8E6ce1x7ryqsGmwf7CX5gk1
         2cbQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@ora.com header.s=pigeon header.b=NfdCD2Lf;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@ora.com designates 52.86.211.29 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@ora.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=test.com
Return-Path: <noreply@test.com>
Received: from o14.pigeon.test.com (o14.pigeon.test.com. [52.86.211.29])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c23si1991658qkc.57.2019.10.09.07.00.43
        for <abc@example.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 09 Oct 2019 07:00:43 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@test.com designates 52.86.211.29 as permitted sender) client-ip=52.86.211.29;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@test.com header.s=pigeon header.b=NfdCD2Lf;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@test.com designates 52.86.211.29 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@test.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=test.com
Received: 
    by pigeon-at-10008 (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTP id bdf7b3a7
    for <abc@example.com>;
    Wed, 9 Oct 2019 14:00:42 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=test.com; h=
    content-type:mime-version:from:to:subject:list-unsubscribe:date
    :message-id; s=pigeon; bh=qQnbMY4RR+Ld/4G3VfGFHTDAbf8=; b=NfdCD2
    LfQ6fEKlj9ngm3hsGnx5wnYqrV3alnQKqKKummUxCCwVUVS0aN/Y+i/SHU8uVAsZ
    z64TMsxyvnwaKT8S5cj3+5YPogkqBJ2nDfRbkKGv9InpGeyV+1zTTCbMYh5RtbrJ
    l5rWYpkwYXdUnG7HO3NjWl0AQDw2uIK1eya5Befe9eFqq6IKF8sno/mxJuWlryjZ
    +9HhiHzaXJsBRoP4K3igh9TSv3PLsU3czd5rqGEmKbuNDeSBsj3zfbWpG13weil7
    bKmfifVoSBuMmwdZ9k4/pqCgzv1LONm7WXt0kWj0tjLLMAVINp2xaBZwslU29kKu
    c0RfXJPvGVNNnSNA==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============7494951501103869667=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: test <question-noreply@test.com>
To: abc@example.com
Subject: =?utf-8?q?Can_you_answer_Calvin_Archar=27s_question=3A_=22Where_can_I_get_a_?=
 =?utf-8?q?perfect_Mbox_conversion=3F=22?=
List-Unsubscribe: <https://www.test.com/email_optout/notif_unsubscribe?snid=5417382280&t=1570629642033459&token=f52913e50a7d2c9c83c042aff173f65d9df85b0f72a29957714dcbbea6c6540298c6bb5131d3f54c257ee26bd028bd7762180f78af8977e98bc7737dab3a4596&type=254&uid=914958709>
X-CID: rLtbYSL6G_26qbjlQKqf1oT47QqaS7okuVAcnMVZKIQLTBMjVpEBJXM8iFXxiiLGtvFhFm6ZrsCKyDaGkInxSMs74v_H4HQiudP94TEnXVao1CyLeomGOK0RLZ6KTv66bsQ0iwABAgA=
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 14:00:42 +0000
Message-ID: <rLtbYSL6G_26qbjlQKqf1oT47QqaS7okuVAcnMVZKIQLTBMjVpEBJXM8iFXxiiLGtvFhFm6ZrsCKyDaGkInxSMs74v_H4HQiudP94TEnXVao1CyLeomGOK0RLZ6KTv66bsQ0iwABAgA=@t1.msgid.testmail.com>
X-SMTPAPI: =?utf-8?q?=7B=22unique=5Fargs=22=3A_=7B=22Message-ID=22=3A_=22=3CrLtbYSL6G?=
 =?utf-8?q?=5F26qbjlQKqf1oT47QqaS7okuVAcnMVZKIQLTBMjVpEBJXM8iFXxiiLGtvFhFm6Z?=
 =?utf-8?q?rsCKyDaGkInxSMs74v=5FH4HQiudP94TEnXVao1CyLeomGOK0RLZ6KTv66bsQ0iwA?=
 =?utf-8?q?BAgA=3D=40t1=2Emsgid=2Etestmail=2Ecom=3E=22=2C_=22account=22=3A_?=
 =?utf-8?q?=22notif=22=2C_=22email=5Ftype=22=3A_103=2C_=22ip=5Fpool=22=3A_?=
 =?utf-8?q?=22notif=22=2C_=22X-QMSG=22=3A_=224C7Z4S8G1tjnwfnPiZm9OQugaHH9844?=
 =?utf-8?q?HQ5Va-HSr8udg4wgNmd-NLgw-m6di=5FU8rQw=5FhpN8sw4GYCnpqUyf1Tcovp=5F?=
 =?utf-8?q?I2CQ=5FZ508Oa4AIb8h=5FnI7t-0cWrhCnTOTRIZZ2wfc4oxbImvem5K-GO=5FkIx?=
 =?utf-8?q?JeRUSMQFrWmIRY7ZGQKilds-hHaR877B4A3Bspq-MHWOktgoABNtSrwdjuXkFhTh2?=
 =?utf-8?q?JoMWbgZDFTZnCMa-1pefnMif4gD2xYaeC7RPKIte3XRkThnzfepAkCjXQq37yS5wR?=
 =?utf-8?q?az9W6un=5FQRrLjSUYuFQO8puiJjTUbxv3Vsni5K64gRqYiyxBNspI5osZOYz41J4?=
 =?utf-8?q?6kUxaSDIDdFSJ5SHNO-wT3cU0ySw9EaeXrQ6pbHyh4CqrhcBKwZT4KyvvT7XVYNZl?=
 =?utf-8?q?pn9s7iLp3FtwKZ3sAAQIA=22=7D=2C_=22category=22=3A_=5B=22account=5F?=
 =?utf-8?q?notif=22=2C_=22email=5Ftype=5F103=22=2C_=22ip=5Fpool=5Fnotif=22?=
 =?utf-8?q?=5D=2C_=22filters=22=3A_=7B=22bypass=5Flist=5Fmanagement=22=3A_?=
 =?utf-8?q?=7B=22settings=22=3A_=7B=22enable=22=3A_1=7D=7D=7D=2C_=22ip=5Fpoo?=
 =?utf-8?q?l=22=3A_=22notif=22=7D?=
X-QMSG: =?utf-8?q?4C7Z4S8G1tjnwfnPiZm9OQugaHH9844HQ5Va-HSr8udg4wgNmd-NLgw-m6di=5FU8r?=
 =?utf-8?q?Qw=5FhpN8sw4GYCnpqUyf1Tcovp=5FI2CQ=5FZ508Oa4AIb8h=5FnI7t-0cWrhCnT?=
 =?utf-8?q?OTRIZZ2wfc4oxbImvem5K-GO=5FkIxJeRUSMQFrWmIRY7ZGQKilds-hHaR877B4A3?=
 =?utf-8?q?Bspq-MHWOktgoABNtSrwdjuXkFhTh2JoMWbgZDFTZnCMa-1pefnMif4gD2xYaeC7R?=
 =?utf-8?q?PKIte3XRkThnzfepAkCjXQq37yS5wRaz9W6un=5FQRrLjSUYuFQO8puiJjTUbxv3V?=
 =?utf-8?q?sni5K64gRqYiyxBNspI5osZOYz41J46kUxaSDIDdFSJ5SHNO-wT3cU0ySw9EaeXrQ?=
 =?utf-8?q?6pbHyh4CqrhcBKwZT4KyvvT7XVYNZlpn9s7iLp3FtwKZ3sAAQIA?=
X-Antivirus: Avast (VPS 210621-8, 06/21/2021), Inbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean

--===============7494951501103869667==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Can you answer this question?
From topics you know about

-----


Can you help answer this question:
Where can I get a perfect Mbox conversion?
https://www.test.com/qemail/track_click?al_imp=3DbnVsbA%3D%3D&al_pri=3DQue=
stionLinkClickthrough&aoid=3DLNA0aQuJUGy&aoty=3D2&aty=3D4&click_pos=3D1&ct=
=3D1570629642018099&et=3D103&id=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff2957507f045985d35&request_=
id=3D254&src=3D1&st=3D1570629642031517&stories=3D5417382280&uid=3Dd3SkvTEmy=
P8&v=3D0
-----

-----
To control which emails we send you, visit: https://www.test.com/qemail/tr=
ack_click?aoid&aoty=3D14&aty=3D4&click_pos=3D0&ct=3D1570629642018099&et=3D1=
03&id=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff2957507f045985d35&request_id=3D254&src=3D1&st=3D1570=
629642031517&stories=3D5417382280&uid=3Dd3SkvTEmyP8&v=3D0

To unsubscribe from this type of email, visit: https://www.test.com/email_=
optout/notif_unsubscribe?snid=3D5417382280&t=3D1570629642037527&token=3D525=
c0860ad7565b318ebceab97cfc5e36ba79bee5206a5f5a3e78fe1c07056e2dee8ee4a1880c7=
88976af17a996c2efc740f2f74ca7cdee9374c7fb52da60492&type=3D254&uid=3D9149587=
09
--===============7494951501103869667==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style type=3D"text/css">@media screen and (max-=
width:480px){.background_inner{padding:0!important;background:#fff!importan=
t}.container{padding:0 8px 16px!important}.footer_container{border-top:1px =
solid #e2e2e2!important}.AnnualThankYouEmail .background_inner{padding:10px=
 0!important}.polish_background_inner{padding:10px 0!important}.polish_head=
er_logo img.header_logo_img{width:118px!important;height:40px!important}.po=
lish_header_title{font-size:16px!important;padding-top:0!important;padding-=
bottom:5px!important}.polish_question_text{line-height:1.3!important}.polis=
h_story .voters_list,.polish_story .user_link{line-height:1.5!important}.po=
lish_story .truncated_q_text,.polish_story .qtext_para{line-height:1.5!impo=
rtant}.polish_story .content_header{padding:6px 0!important}.EndOfYearLookb=
ackEmail .stat_large{font-size:28px!important}.EndOfYearLookbackEmail .cont=
ent_text{text-align:center!important}.EndOfYearLookbackEmail .half_column{w=
idth:100%!important}.EndOfYearLookbackEmail .img_wrapper{margin:10px auto!i=
mportant}.TopicDigestEmail .topic_digest_header_logo img.polish_header_logo=
_img{width:89px!important;height:30px!important}.TopicDigestEmail .topic_di=
gest_header_title{font-size:16px!important;padding-top:0!important;padding-=
bottom:5px!important}.WriteDigestEmail .question_text .rendered_qtext{font-=
size:16px!important}.email_app_link-content{display:block!important;text-al=
ign:center!important}.email_app_link-text,.email_app_link-badges_wrapper{di=
splay:block!important}.email_app_link-text{padding-bottom:0!important;box-s=
izing:border-box!important}.email_app_link-badges_wrapper{padding-left:10px=
!important}}@media screen and (max-width:600px){.DigestEmail .mobile_image.=
digest_ad{display:table!important;width:92vw}.DigestEmail .desktop_image.di=
gest_ad{display:none!important}}</style></head><body class=3D"email_body"><=
table class=3D"Email SystemA2ANotifEmail EmailComponent BaseNotifEmail Noti=
fEmail background" cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse:=
 collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; background: #eee; font=
-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; widt=
h: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: left;" width=3D"100%" height=3D"100%" al=
ign=3D"left"><tbody><tr><td class=3D"polish_background_inner" align=3D"cent=
er" valign=3D"top" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; backgrou=
nd: #fff;"><table cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" style=3D=
"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tbo=
dy><tr><td class=3D"container" align=3D"left" style=3D"border-collapse: col=
lapse; background: #fff; padding: 30px; width: 525px; height: 100%; border-=
radius: 3px;" width=3D"525" height=3D"100%"><table class=3D"polish_containe=
r_inner" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table=
-rspace: 0; width: 100%; cellpadding: 0; cellspacing: 0; border: 0;" width=
=3D"100%"><tbody><tr><td class=3D"polish_header" style=3D"border-collapse: =
collapse;"><span style=3D"color:white; font-size:1px; display:block;"></spa=
n><table cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" width=3D"100%" st=
yle=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;=
"><tbody><tr><td class=3D"polish_header_logo" style=3D"border-collapse: col=
lapse; text-align: center;" align=3D"center"><a href=3D"https://www.test.c=
om/qemail/track_click?aoid&amp;aoty=3D7&amp;aty=3D4&amp;click_pos=3D0&amp;c=
t=3D1570629642018099&amp;et=3D103&amp;id=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff2957507f045985d35=
&amp;request_id=3D254&amp;src=3D1&amp;st=3D1570629642031517&amp;stories=3D5=
417382280&amp;uid=3Dd3SkvTEmyP8&amp;v=3D0" style=3D"text-decoration: none; =
color: #2b6dad;"><img class=3D"header_logo_img" src=3D"https://qsf.fs.test=
cdn.net/-3-images.logo.WordmarkLogo_bg_592x200_4x.png-26-60d621643a41c203.p=
ng" alt=3D"test" style=3D"outline: 0; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpola=
tion-mode: bicubic; border: 0; width: 148px; height: 50px;" width=3D"148" h=
eight=3D"50"></a></td></tr><tr><td class=3D"polish_header_title" style=3D"b=
order-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: 19px; font-family:=
 Georgia,Times,'Times New Roman',serif; color: #333; font-weight: 400; padd=
ing-bottom: 20px;" align=3D"center">Can you answer this question?</td></tr>=
<tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"><table class=3D"polish_header_=
wrapper" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table=
-rspace: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; cellpadding: 0; border: 0; width: 100%;" w=
idth=3D"100%"><tbody><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"></td><td =
class=3D"polish_header_line" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; border-bot=
tom: 1px solid #b92b27; height: 1px; width: 198px;" width=3D"198" height=3D=
"1"></td><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"></td></tr></tbody></table=
></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr class=3D"body_container" id=3D"sim=
ple-content-row"><td class=3D"body_content" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff" style=3D"bo=
rder-collapse: collapse;"><table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-ta=
ble-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; width: 100%;" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspa=
cing=3D"0" border=3D"0" width=3D"100%"><tbody><tr><td style=3D"border-colla=
pse: collapse;"><table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace=
: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; width: 100%;" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0"=
 border=3D"0" width=3D"100%"><tbody><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: colla=
pse;"><div data-clog-trigger=3D"impression" data-clog-metadata=3D"{&quot;ac=
tion_log_target&quot;: {&quot;type&quot;: 36, &quot;hash&quot;: -1100246126=
}}" data-clog-event-type=3D"ActionLogImpression" id=3D"__w2_w4gAZxDS4_actio=
nable"><table class=3D"question_to_answer" width=3D"100%" cellpadding=3D"0"=
 cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-tab=
le-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tr height=3D"20">&nbsp;</tr><tr class=
=3D"sell_line" height=3D"20"><td class=3D"icon_section" width=3D"50" style=
=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"><div align=3D"right"><div id=3D"w4gAZxDS5">=
<img class=3D"topic_photo_img" src=3D"https://qph.fs.testcdn.net/main-thum=
b-t-1774-50-nyslvxaepwdvpwotaguyvglpkapunmeu.jpeg" alt=3D"Personal Storage =
Table" height=3D"50" width=3D"50" style=3D"outline: 0; text-decoration: non=
e; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"></div></div></td><td width=3D"15" styl=
e=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td><td style=3D"border-collapse: c=
ollapse; vertical-align: top;" valign=3D"top"><div class=3D"question_metada=
ta">As someone who answered questions about <strong>Personal Storage Table<=
/strong> before, can you help Calvin Archar?</div></td></tr></table><div st=
yle=3D"height:15px;"></div><table class=3D"question_to_answer" width=3D"100=
%" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" style=3D"border-collaps=
e: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;"><tr><td class=3D"ic=
on_section user_photo" width=3D"35" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; ver=
tical-align: top;" valign=3D"top"><div id=3D"w4gAZxDS7"><div class=3D"hover=
_menu hidden white_bg show_nub" id=3D"__w2_w4gAZxDS8_menu"><div class=3D"ho=
ver_menu_contents" id=3D"__w2_w4gAZxDS8_menu_contents"> </div></div><span c=
lass=3D"photo_tooltip IdentityPhoto Photo HoverMenu" id=3D"__w2_w4gAZxDS8_l=
ink"><img class=3D"profile_photo_img" src=3D"https://qsf.fs.testcdn.net/-3=
-images.new_grid.profile_pic_default_small.png-26-679bc670f786484c.png" alt=
=3D"Calvin Archar" height=3D"50" width=3D"50" style=3D"outline: 0; text-dec=
oration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block; height: 50p=
x; width: 50px; border-radius: 100px;"></span></div></td><td width=3D"15" s=
tyle=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"></td><td style=3D"border-collapse: coll=
apse;"><div></div><table width=3D"100%" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0"=
 border=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-=
table-rspace: 0;"><tr class=3D"sell_line"><td style=3D"border-collapse: col=
lapse;"><div class=3D"question_metadata"><strong>Calvin Archar</strong> wan=
ts an answer to:</div></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;=
"><div class=3D"question_row"><a class=3D"question_text" href=3D"https://ww=
w.test.com/qemail/track_click?al_imp=3DeyJ0eXBlIjogMzYsICJoYXNoIjogLTExMDA=
yNDYxMjZ9&amp;al_pri=3DQuestionLinkClickthrough&amp;aoid=3DLNA0aQuJUGy&amp;=
aoty=3D2&amp;aty=3D4&amp;click_pos=3D1&amp;ct=3D1570629642018099&amp;et=3D1=
03&amp;id=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff2957507f045985d35&amp;request_id=3D254&amp;src=
=3D1&amp;st=3D1570629642031517&amp;stories=3D5417382280&amp;uid=3Dd3SkvTEmy=
P8&amp;v=3D0" style=3D"text-decoration: none; display: block; font-size: 19=
px; color: #333; letter-spacing: -0.5px; line-height: 1.25; font-weight: bo=
ld; color: #2b6dad;"><span class=3D"rendered_qtext" style=3D"word-break: br=
eak-word;">Where can I get a perfect Mbox conversion?</span></a=
></div></td></tr><tr height=3D"15"></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: c=
ollapse;"><a class=3D"primary_button" href=3D"https://www.test.com/qemail/=
track_click?al_imp=3DeyJ0eXBlIjogMzYsICJoYXNoIjogLTExMDAyNDYxMjZ9&amp;al_pr=
i=3DWriterEmailWriteAnswerButtonClick&amp;aoid=3DLNA0aQuJUGy&amp;aoty=3D2&a=
mp;aty=3D9&amp;click_pos=3D1&amp;ct=3D1570629642018099&amp;et=3D103&amp;id=
=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff2957507f045985d35&amp;request_id=3D254&amp;src=3D1&amp;st=
=3D1570629642031517&amp;stories=3D5417382280&amp;uid=3Dd3SkvTEmyP8&amp;v=3D=
0" style=3D"text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px; background: #d=
feffa; color: #2770bd; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #75a6d4; border=
-radius: 2px;">Write Answer</a></td></tr><tr height=3D"15"></tr><tr><td sty=
le=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">Can&#039;t answer this question? <strong>=
<a class=3D"decline_question" href=3D"https://www.test.com/qemail/track_cl=
ick?al_imp=3DeyJ0eXBlIjogMzYsICJoYXNoIjogLTExMDAyNDYxMjZ9&amp;al_pri=3DPass=
QuestionButtonClick&amp;aoid=3DLNA0aQuJUGy&amp;aoty=3D2&amp;aty=3D10&amp;cl=
ick_pos=3D1&amp;ct=3D1570629642018099&amp;et=3D103&amp;id=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff=
2957507f045985d35&amp;request_id=3D254&amp;src=3D1&amp;st=3D157062964203151=
7&amp;stories=3D5417382280&amp;uid=3Dd3SkvTEmyP8&amp;v=3D0" style=3D"text-d=
ecoration: none; color: #2b6dad;">Pass on this question</a></strong>.</td><=
/tr><tr height=3D"10"></tr><tr class=3D"request_details" style=3D"color: #9=
99;"><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"><span class=3D"edit_knows_abo=
ut_link" style=3D"text-decoration: underline;"><a href=3D"https://www.test=
.com/profile/John-Doe-546/?edit_knows_about=3D1" style=3D"text-decorati=
on: none; color: #999;">Edit topics you know about</a></span> to improve yo=
ur suggestions. </td></tr><tr height=3D"15"></tr></table></td></tr></table>=
</div><div style=3D"border: 1px solid #eee;"></div></td></tr></tbody></tabl=
e></td><td class=3D"w30" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></=
tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"><=
/td></tr><tr><td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"></td></tr></tbody></t=
able></td></tr><tr><td class=3D"polish_footer_section footer_container_wrap=
per" align=3D"center" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; max-width: 525px;=
 margin-top: 15px;"><table class=3D"footer_container" cellpadding=3D"0" cel=
lspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" style=3D"border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-l=
space: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; font-size: 11px; color: #999; padding-top: 1=
5px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" width=3D"100%" align=3D"center"><tr>=
<td style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;"><div class=3D"footer_text_wrapper"=
 style=3D"padding: 25px 20px;"><div><span style=3D"display: block; padding-=
bottom: 8px; color: #999;">This email was sent by test (650 Castro Street =
#450, Mountain View, CA 94041). </span><span style=3D"display: block; paddi=
ng-bottom: 8px; color: #999;">If you don&#039;t want to receive this type o=
f email in the future, please <a class=3D"unsubscribe_link" href=3D"https:/=
/www.test.com/email_optout/notif_unsubscribe?snid=3D5417382280&amp;t=3D157=
0629642106498&amp;token=3Dbba1b742c57cf8d17fadab4e6a79b57720fd7619c61519bf9=
ca4aba7744b5b279b69711fc72383a67e8692e95d00c4cc445dd3e323e567af482866b0b75e=
15f6&amp;type=3D254&amp;uid=3D914958709" style=3D"color: #999; text-decorat=
ion: underline;">unsubscribe</a>.<img class=3D"tracking_img" style=3D"outli=
ne: 0; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: non=
e;" width=3D"1" height=3D"1" src=3D"https://www.test.com/qemail/mark_read?=
ct=3D1570629642018099&amp;et=3D103&amp;id=3Db9b6cca5ee4e4ff2957507f045985d3=
5&amp;request_id=3D254&amp;src=3D1&amp;st=3D1570629642031517&amp;stories=3D=
5417382280&amp;uid=3Dd3SkvTEmyP8&amp;v=3D0"></span><span style=3D"display: =
block; padding-bottom: 8px; color: #999;"><a href=3D"https://www.test.com/=
" style=3D"color: #999; text-decoration: underline;">https://www.test.com/=
</a></span></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></t=
r></tbody></table>
<style type=3D"text/css">
@media (max-width:812px) {
  .ad_email_background .ad_table {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width:812px) {
  .ad_email_background .ad_table {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
</style></body></html>


From my reading of the mbox file format, any line beginning with "From" marks the start of a new message. Is this the point at which MimeKit is splitting the message? If so, looks like it's parsing the file as intended, and your file contains ambiguities

It should distinguish From  from From:.  The marker is From followed by a whitespace. But still the info where it got split should be telling.

Thank you, canton7. You're right that lines starting with "From " mark new messages in MBOX files. However, some email bodies contain "From " lines (e.g., "Can you answer this question? From topics you know about"), causing MimeKit to split a single email into two parts. These MBOX files are from real-life emails, not generated by me. With over 22,456 emails, other libraries correctly count 22,282 without issues. I'm unsure how to prevent MimeKit from misinterpreting these embedded "From " lines. Any suggestions?

How the mbox file got created? Actually if there are lines starting with From  in the mail they should be "escaped" as >From by the creator of the mbox file.

Thank you, @Ralf. Yes, "From " followed by a space is the MBOX delimiter, while "From:" is an email header. However, some real-life emails include "From " within the body (e.g., "From topics you know about"), causing MimeKit to incorrectly split the email into two parts. These are genuine emails, and I don't have control over their formatting. I'm unsure how to programmatically prevent this with MimeKit. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Hi @Ralf The problematic emails originate from a Q&A site and were exported using Thunderbird.Since these are real-life emails generated by Thunderbird, I'm unsure how to handle this programmatically. Any suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated!

If a message body contains From  (From SPACE), it needs to get escaped properly in order for any mbox parser (including MimeKit's). If Thunderbird is not doing proper escaping, then that's a bug in Thunderbird. The most common form of escape is >From , but since the MIME part containing that text has Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable, you can escape it using =46rom  (which is quoted-printable encoded).
